# No provider for Http error when sharing code between Web and Mobile(NativeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to create a project with Angular 4 and NativeScript with a single codebase as mentioned in [this article](http://shripalsoni.com/blog/create-native-mobile-and-web-app-with-single-codebase-using-angular2-and-nativescript/).

My directory structure looks something like this.

```
project    
└───nativescript
└───node_modules
└───web 
│   └───src
|       └───app
|           └───dashboard
|               └───subcomp
│                   │   subcomp.component.ts
│                   │   subcomp.component.html
|    | package.json
|    | node_modules
└───x-shared
|   └───app
|       └───dashboard
|       |    dashboard.service.ts
```

**There is a symlink to x-shared inside web/src/app.**

web/src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SubComp } from './dashboard/subcomp/subcomp.component';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    SubComp
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

web/src/app/dashboard/subcomp.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from "../../x-shared/app/dashboard/dashboard.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'sub-comp',
  templateUrl: './sub-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-comp.component.css'],
  providers: [DashboardService]
})
export class SubComp implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    // call a method in dashboardService that makes a http call
  });
 }
}
```

The web version will run fine if there was an actual directory named x-shared inside web/src/app. However, it gives the error

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!

when it is a symlink.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo In the question you have linked, OP is trying to load HttpModule into the app. Mine is different since I'm trying to load a service that uses the HttpModule from a symlinked directory.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript uses a wrapper for Angular HTTP. 
Make sure you are using the `nativescript-angular/http` module

app.module.ts

```
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";

...

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
    }
})
```

Comment: I have loaded it into the NativeScript app. The issue is with the web version.